# How to drop the caches on AIX?

Tags: aix

I am running a series of tests from a script that have a habit of running a box out of memory. The simple solution on other linux boxes is to [echo "3" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/buffer_cache.html) but this command doesn't work on AIX. Is there an AIX equivalent to this command?

Comment: You'll probably have to address this to IBM support, as this is a proprietary UNIX system without all the nice things that Linux has for us.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to drop the caches in AIX.